# Get Follower Count in Linkedin using API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am looking to get the follower count for a page (not a company page) I manage using the Linkedin API. It appears this is a more difficult process than it should be.

Does anyone have any advice on how to get this endpoint? Seems a very simple metric but I cannot find it in the documentation.

I track the performance and growth of a number of pages I manage across numerous platforms. I'd like to also add Linkedin to these measurements and having this process automated would be helpful.

I have contacted LinkedIn directly for help and advice in this matter and was told to post a question here and tag LinkedIn in the question so it was seen by LinkedIn engineers.

Any help would be great, Thanks.